# How to get a Android menu drop down like the one in Wash Post app?

Tags: android, menu

I want to create a similar drop down menu using the grid button on the top right corner like the one the Wash Post android app.

I went through the web. But could find any answers, as I am new and really don't know what keywords to search with.

Comment: can you please attached the screen shoot or app link please...

Comment: nobody is going to download the app to see what you are talking about, a screencap would help a lot

Comment: I am a new user. I need 10 rep to add the screencap.

Answer (score 1):

The library [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) is able to do that in targets below Android 3.0 - it's available since Honeycomb via the normal menu mechanism.

If you want your items to appear in that dropdown - just define the right flag

[SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)